# AWS s3 lifecycle policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-config, s3-lifecycle-policy

we are checking if lifecycle policies are applied (compliant) to all prefixes individually ( not inherited from parent bucket) . we are capturing the event from AWS config and if the lifecycle policy is changed. Is there a way to trace which lifecycle rule has changed or which prefix lifecycle has changed.   So we dont have to scan all the prefixes in bucket and check the if lifecycle policy is compliant only check the prefix whose rule has changed .

Answer (score 0):

check in cloudtrail if event PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration has been created on bucket.
this event PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration is used for creating new bucket lifecycle policy or update existing life cycle policy.

Comment: But that would be bucket level and i have to check each prefix to check it that prefix is affected due to change in lifecylcle rule.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Did you find any other solution ?